# API call in express says maximum rows exceeded

Tags: javascript, express

I have an express app that makes an api call and prints out the results like so:

```js
 const PORT = 8000
const express = require ('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const axios = require('axios')



app.use(cors())

const app = express()

 app.get('/acs_chart', (req,res) => { 
   (API Call)
  async function APICall(){
    const result = await fetch(url, opts).then(res => res.json()) 
   
      
       res.json(result)
  }
  bitqueryAPICall()
  
  }
  
)

app.listen(8000, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`))
```

The issue now is that once the API call is made, the result says

> Limit for result exceeded, max rows: 25.00 thousand, current rows: 40.11 thousand

I know that you can increase the file size, but I don't think that also increases the maximum number of rows. Is there a way to increase the maximum number of rows?

Comment: What "file size" do you want to increase? And how would that be related to the limits of that API?

Comment: "*Is there a way to increase the maximum number of rows?*" - yes: talk to the provider of the API.

Comment: This isn't a question for SO but for the provider of the API you use. It's also not related to Express at all.

Comment: It sounds like some kind of rate limiting on API. Probably you need a pagination param or similar. Check the API docs…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api that returns row in thousands should have pagination support. send pagination parameter to get paged data based on threshold set from api provider. If you are owner of the api you should add support for server side pagination.